# Value passed to time.sleep() determines whether code fails or not

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7

I'm not sure what's going on here but my code fails with exit code 15 and no other errors messages depending on what value I pass to time.sleep()

```
import docker, docker.utils, time
Thread(target = partial(image_runner.run, create_biobox_args(app))).start()

time.sleep(1)
client = docker.Client(**docker.utils.kwargs_from_env(assert_hostname = False))
container = filter(lambda x: x['Image'] == name, client.containers())[0]['Id']
while client.inspect_container(container)["State"]["Status"] == "running":
    time.sleep(20)
```

I have a docker container started in another thread with `Thread(...).start()`. However if I use `time.sleep()` with a value greater than 10 my code will fail with exit code 15, but work otherwise. Any idea what's going on here? I've been trying to debug this but haven't a clue.

Comment: There are two calls to `sleep()`, making your question unclear. Also, "exit code 15", on which OS is that? Further, what if you keep a reference to the created `Thread` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my feature tests timeout after 10 seconds and this what causes the problem. Adjusting the length of the cucumber feature tests default timeout fixes this problem.